# Rails - Couldn't find Variant without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing this error *Couldn't find Variant without an ID*

I don't get what is wrong :(

**Stock**  belongs_to :variant

**Variant**  has_many :stocks and belongs_to :product

**Product**

```
has_many :variants, inverse_of: :product, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :stocks, through: :variants

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants
```

**stock.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(Stock.new, url: admin_stocks_path) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :variant_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@product.variants, :id, :size),required: true %>
    <%= f.input :quantity, required: true %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**stocks_controller.rb**

```
 class StocksController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @stock = Stock.find(params[:id])
    end

    def index
        @stocks = Stock.all
        @variants = Variant.all
    end

    def new 
        @stock = Stock.new
        @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @variants = @product.variants
    end

    def create
        find_variant
        @product = @variant.product
        @stock = Stock.new(stock_params)
        if @stock.save
            redirect_to  stock_product_path(@product)
        else
            redirect_to stock_product_path(@product), alert: "Woops"
        end
    end

    private

    def stock_params
        params.require(:stock).permit(:id, :quantity, :variant_id )
    end

    def find_variant
        @variant = Variant.find(params[:variant_id])
    end
end
```

I did fake the `find_variant`method with  `Variant.find(2)` and it was working... 
Why I can't find the `:variant_id`?

here is my table stocks from my schema.rb

```
 create_table "stocks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.bigint "variant_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["variant_id"], name: "index_stocks_on_variant_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params[:variant_id]` will not be the value.  You meant `stock_params[:variant_id]`

Comment: Oh dear I didn't know we could do that, many many thanks, will accept your answer when I am allowed to